# I want to add a new column using SELECT query and get a latest value from multiple columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

| Outcome1 | Outcome2 | Outcome3 | Outcome4 | DESIRED OUTCOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | CR | CR |
| CR | C | CR | CR | CR |
|  |  | N | CR | N |
|  |  |  | CR | CR |
|  |  | C | C | C |
|  |  |  | C | C |
|  |  |  | C | C |
|  |  |  | CC | CC |
| CR |  | CC | CC | CR |

Answer (score 1):

It seems you simply need the first not-null value. If so, You can use COALESCE function -

```
SELECT COALESCE(Outcome1, Outcome2, Outcome3, Outcome4)
  FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Ok, I got my answer now.